# Positioning an ffmpeg text while wrapping text in newlines

Tags: ffmpeg, python, video-editing

I would like to automatically wrap text in multiple lines if it is too long to fit on the screen.

[I know about the subtitle option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50630035/5123111) but it is not what I am seeking for. When generating a long video with hundreds of texts, it would be an overkill to have all those I/O operations of writing each of these .srt files to local storage, just to then have to remove them.

What I am currently attempting to use is based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74025395/5123111). I'm using a custom method that adds newlines after every N number of characters. The problem in this case, however, is that I seem to lose the centered positioning of my text, despite the x, y setting being correct:

```
"-vf", f"drawtext=text='{sentence}':fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2"
```

My minimal reproducible example is:

```
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path
from langvidgen import FONTS_FOLDER

CURRENT_DIR = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()

font_path = str(FONTS_FOLDER / "Montserrat-MediumItalic.ttf")
font_path = font_path.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("c:", "c\:")

def split_txt_into_multi_lines(input_str: str, line_length: int):
    words = input_str.split(" ")
    line_count = 0
    split_input = ""
    for word in words:
        line_count += 1
        line_count += len(word)
        if line_count > line_length:
            split_input += "\n"
            line_count = len(word) + 1
            split_input += word
            split_input += " "
        else:
            split_input += word
            split_input += " "
    
    return split_input

sentence = 'This is a long text that won\u2019t fit in a single line. We need to automatically wrap it into multiple lines, depending on its length.'
sentence = split_txt_into_multi_lines(sentence, line_length=30)

ffmpeg_command = [
    "ffmpeg",
    "-y",
    "-f",
    "lavfi",
    "-i",
    "color=c=gray:s=640x480:d=4",
    "-vf",
    f"drawtext=text='{sentence}':fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontfile='{font_path}'",
    str(CURRENT_DIR / "output.mp4"),
]

subprocess.run(ffmpeg_command)
```

This is what appears:
[image]

Comment: You'll need to use subtitles - you can have all those hundreds of subs in one ASS file.